# Node - Heroku - static IP without verifying account

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I deployed my node backend to heroku - it makes API calls with a token that is whitelisted to a specific public IP. Now we know heroku works dynamic IPs and offers static IP's only by using addons which require a credit card. Does anyone has another (non-cost) approach how to solve this issue?

Comment: there must be alt. to "whitelist by fixd IP"  if that is all they offer with their API then id drop the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku requires credit card only to use addons, and alot of addons are free to use. They won't charge you anything if you don't choose some paid plan. Plus you get 450 free dyno hours every month if you give your credit card details. So it's not a bad idea to use it.

Comment: should have mentioned in the question, i dont have any credit card - and the limitations are quit big for the free addon versions: therefore has anyone another approach for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an Add-on, like Proximo, if you require a static IP address.

This help article explains in detail:

https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-whitelist-heroku-dynos-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku